# title attribute not working on jquery radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The title I am applying to a jquery radio button is not appearing when I hover over the button. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<input type="radio" id="workcenters2" name="workcenters" value="Order Entry" title="Order Entry"><label for="workcenters2">OE</label>
```

Comment: title is not an valid input attribut

Comment: Make sure you are hovering over the radio button and not the OE label.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment but I can't...

What browser? Title should work fine in any modern browser, and it is actually valid HTML(4.01 and 5). I also made a quick jsfiddle and it works fine for me.

Comment: and what doctype? 4.01 strict, transitional or 5.0? are you hovering over the text, and not the radio icon?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> and i'm hovering over the button, as far away from the label as possible

Comment: Need to see full HTML/page itself in order to further diagnose, as it's unclear what the problem is at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Using jqueryui buttonset seems to be causing the problem.

I put the title attribute within the label tag and it works now, although not sure why.